# Not able to get show coma separated values in codeigniter view

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, foreach, multipleselection

i having this array i am not getting area_tutor because it has values with comma

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [tuitor_id] => 288
            [mobile_tuitor] => 0123456789
            [alt_mobile_tuitor] => 
            [fullname_tuitor] => 
            [gender_tuitor] => male
            [city_tutor] => 2
            [area_tutor] => 7,8,9
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [tuitor_id] => 287
            [mobile_tuitor] => 2568798456
            [alt_mobile_tuitor] => 
            [fullname_tuitor] => sumit test new filed
            [gender_tuitor] => male
            [city_tutor] => 1
            [area_tutor] => 3
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [tuitor_id] => 285
            [mobile_tuitor] => 1452587658
            [alt_mobile_tuitor] => 0789578469
            [fullname_tuitor] => Sumit Nair
            [gender_tuitor] => male
            [city_tutor] => 1
            [area_tutor] => 1,2,3,4
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [tuitor_id] => 273
            [mobile_tuitor] => 0954652478
            [alt_mobile_tuitor] => 
            [fullname_tuitor] => vbvbbb
            [gender_tuitor] => female
            [city_tutor] => 1
            [area_tutor] => 3
        )

    [4] => stdClass Object
        (
            [tuitor_id] => 225
            [profile_title] => 
            [mobile_tuitor] => 4557821212
            [alt_mobile_tuitor] => 5445587112
            [fullname_tuitor] => xyz
            [gender_tuitor] => male
            [city_tutor] => 4
            [area_tutor] => 14
        )

)
```

where area_tutor has values with commas which i am not getting while retrieving from foeach loop i am only getting first element of area_tutor , this is how i am looping with foreach loop

```
$this->db->select('*')->from('tuitor');
$this->db->order_by("tuitor_id", "desc");
$this->db->join('city_tuitor', 'tuitor.city_tutor = city_tuitor.city_id', 'left');
$this->db->join('area_tuitor', 'tuitor.area_tutor = area_tuitor.area_id', 'left');

$query=$this->db->get();
return $result = $query->result();
```

Now in view i am simply looping through foreach loop

if i am printing like this i am getting i am getting the above aray
    
    print_r($result);

But when i am trying to echo values at that time i am getting only first value of area_tutor

```
 <?php  foreach($result as $r) { ?>
    echo $r->tuitor_id; 
    echo $r->mobile_tuitor;
    echo $r->city_tutor;
    echo $r->area_tutor;
    <?php } ?>
```

Please help me out how can i get all the values of area_tutor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try the simple method to print values..

```
<?php 
$result = $query->result_array();
foreach($result as $key=>$val)
{
    echo $val['tuitor_id'];
    echo $val['mobile_tuitor'];
    echo $val['city_tutor'];
    echo $val['area_tutor'];
}
?>
```

Comment: Message: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array .... Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in

Comment: do i need to change anything in model ?

Comment: no need to change anything in the model just add `$result= json_decode($result,true);` this line above foreach loop

Comment: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given this i am getting now sorry yaar i am troubling you but still i can get :(

Comment: replace this line `$result = $query->result();` with  `$result = $query->result_array();` and remove this line `$result= json_decode($result,true);`

Comment: Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() getting this

Comment: yaaar ye he aaraa hai Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: in result i am getting [area_tutor] => 7,8,9 and entire array

Comment: waaao its comming but still one problem is there i have joined this area table so i am only getting the first area like when i am doing this $val['area_name']; i am only getting first area name any idea what should i do ?

Comment: bahi area_tutor ko explode kar le `explode(',',$val['area_tutor'];)` array ban jayega iska aur us array par foreach lga le

Comment: jeee baat thanks yaar thanks mere bhai thankyou yaar :) jaan bacha li mere :D

Comment: welcome brother :)  koi bhi problem ho yaad karna bhai ko.. goodluck

Comment: bilkul bhai :) can i have your fb id ?

Comment: hey i try exploding $cats = explode(',',$val['area_name']);
    
foreach($cats as  $vald) {
 
 echo $vald;
}but i am only getting first area name any suggestion can i change anything in join ?

Comment: why exploding `$val['area_name']` ?? you need to explode the id's of area tutor i.e. `$val['area_tutor']`

Comment: hey bro its working super thanks buddy :) thanks a ton :)
 :)

Answer (score 1):

try to use `where_in()`

```
$this->db->where_in();

Generates a WHERE field IN ('item', 'item') SQL query joined with AND if appropriate

$area_tutor= array('1', '2', '3');
$this->db->where_in('area_tutor', $area_tutor);
// Produces: WHERE area_tutor IN ('1', '2', '3')
```

[visit here for more information](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html)

Comment: yaar it's not working can you elaborate little bit what should i do ?

Comment: when i am doing print_r($result); i am getting area's but when i going for echo $r->area_tutor; it is only showing one value

Comment: i got the same output which you can see above the entire array

Comment: this array i got by print_r only

Comment: bhai please help kar de :( pata he nae chal paara kaise values lu multidimensional array ka use karna hoga ky ?